Numbering a carbon chain
I would like to be able to number the carbons in the main chain to show how organic species are named.
an example (but which does not correspond to my code)

What is the best method?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}


\chemfig{-[:30,,,,red]-[:-30,,,,red](-[:-90])-[:30,,,,red]-[:-30,,,,red](-[:-90])-[:30,,,,red]-[:-30,,,,red]}

\end{document}


Can you show a sketch how the result should look like?

I edited my post with an image

Thanks! This makes your question much clearer!

I would use \chemabove or \chembelow.
Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{
  {\chembelow[3pt]{}{1}}
  -[:30,,,,red]     \chemabove[3pt]{}{2}
  -[:-30,,,,red]    \chemabove[3pt]{}{3} (-[:-90])
  -[:30,,,,red]     \chemabove[3pt]{}{4}
  -[:-30,,,,red]    \chemabove[3pt]{}{5}  (-[:-90])
  -[:30,,,,red]     \chemabove[3pt]{}{6}
  -[:-30,,,,red]
}

\end{document}


EDIT
To fix the bounding box, one can add baseline=1.6em (many thanks to @Atex).
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\chemfig
  {\chembelow[3pt]{}{1}}
  -[:30,,,,red]     \chemabove[3pt]{}{2}
  -[:-30,,,,red]    \chemabove[3pt]{}{3} (-[:-90])
  -[:30,,,,red]     \chemabove[3pt]{}{4}
  -[:-30,,,,red]    \chemabove[3pt]{}{5}  (-[:-90])
  -[:30,,,,red]     \chemabove[3pt]{}{6}
  -[:-30,,,,red]
}

\lipsum[2]

\chemfig[baseline=1.6em]{
  {\chembelow[3pt]{}{1}}
  -[:30,,,,red]     \chemabove[3pt]{}{2}
  -[:-30,,,,red]    \chemabove[3pt]{}{3} (-[:-90])
  -[:30,,,,red]     \chemabove[3pt]{}{4}
  -[:-30,,,,red]    \chemabove[3pt]{}{5}  (-[:-90])
  -[:30,,,,red]     \chemabove[3pt]{}{6}
  -[:-30,,,,red]
}

\end{document}



When adding a paragraph of text before the figure, it seems that the above numbers slightly overlap with the use of the parskip package. Without it, the numbers overlap the text completely. I'd assume the same would happen for a paragraph below if you had added numbering for the vertical lines below them. Any chance the answer could be updated with a solution to this?

I dug a little deeper, and found the solution at the bottom of page 30. The baseline is set to 0pt by default, and thus you have to manually change it by adding an optional parameter \chemfig[baseline=<height>] in order to adjust the distance of the figure from your paragraphs.

@Atex Nice, I added it to the answer. Thanks.

There might be an easier way, but you could use tikz to add labels:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}


\chemfig{@{x1}-[:30,,,,red]@{x2}-[:-30,,,,red](@{x3}-[:-90])-[:30,,,,red]-[:-30,,,,red](-[:-90])-[:30,,,,red]-[:-30,,,,red]}
\chemmove{
  \node[above] at (x1) {1};
  \node[above] at (x2) {2};
  \node[above] at (x3) {3};
}

\end{document}



Nevermind, I retract my statement. It seems that a solution to the vertical alignment in relation to a paragraph has been mentioned in the documentation, but it has been mentioned all the way down at the bottom of page 30. Thus, one can fix the issue of text alignment simply by adding \chemfig[baseline=<height>] to insert distance from paragraph to figure. The default value is sett to 0pt, hence the issue
